# should this be mocked or stubbed?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, c#-4.0, dependency-injection, moq

I have the following method to test and i have written two tests, testing the scenario that an exception is thrown, and im wondering which is correct.

```
namespace JimBob.CsvImporter.Entity
{

    public interface IIOManager
    {
        Stream OpenFile(string path);

        TextReader ReturnReader(string path);
    }


    public class IOManager : IIOManager
    {
        public Stream OpenFile(string path)
        {
            return File.Open(path, FileMode.Open);
        }

        public TextReader ReturnReader(string filePath)
        {
            return new StreamReader(filePath);
        }
    }


public class EntityVerification
{

    private IIOManager _iomgr;

    public EntityVerification(IIOManager ioManager)
    {
        this._iomgr = ioManager;
    }

    ...

    /// <summary>
    /// Ensures user can open file.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="errorMessageList">A running list of all errors encountered.</param>
    public void ValidateAccessToFile(string filePath, List<string> errorMessageList)
    {
        try
        {
            using (FileStream fs = (FileStream)_iomgr.OpenFile(filePath))
            {
                if (fs.CanRead && fs.CanWrite) { }
                else
                {
                    errorMessageList.Add("Can not read/write to the specified file.");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            errorMessageList.Add(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

Tests:

```
    [Test]
    public void ValidateAccessToFile_CanReadWriteToFile_ThrowException()
    {
        List<String> errorMessageList = new List<string>();
        StubService stub = new StubService();
        EntityVerification testObject = new EntityVerification(stub);
        testObject.ValidateAccessToFile("ergesrg", errorMessageList);
        Assert.AreEqual(errorMessageList.Count, 0);
    }

    [Test]
    public void ValidateAccessToFile_CanReadWriteToFile_ThrowsException()
    {
        Mock<IIOManager> mock = new Mock<IIOManager>();
        mock.Setup(x => x.ReturnReader(It.IsAny<string>())).Throws(new InvalidOperation("throw baby."));
        EntityVerification testObject = new EntityVerification(mock.Object);
        List<String> errorMessageList = new List<string>();
        testObject.ValidateAccessToFile("blabla.txt", errorMessageList);
        Assert.AreEqual(errorMessageList.Count, 0);
    }



    public class StubService : IIOManager
    {
        public Exception ex;
        public Stream OpenFile(String path)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Both tests just check that a local variable, in this case errorMessageList, to the test contains something so im not sure which i should be using.

Any comments would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, shouldn't you be checking that you **do** add an error message to the list?

```
Assert.AreEqual(errorMessageList.Count, 1);
```

Second, although the second one is a little less verbose, and more readable (as you don't need to implement another class), **it doesn't matter** - the two tests are both valid ways of achieving the same target. Just choose one and move on to your next feature...

Comment: Not sure i follow why i shouldnt be checking that it adds a message. Im not rethrowing the exception so i need to check its adding something to the errorMessageList so i can determine if its possible to proceed to the next stage in the program or not.

Comment: Yeah, so check that the list holds **one** message, not **zero**... Or use `Assert.That(errorMessageList, Is.Not.Empty);`.

Answer (score 1):

Second test looks better. I think you'll have other methods with `IIOManager` you should maintain 1st test (update stub), but do nothing on the second one.

About `IOManager`, `FileSystem` - looks more suitable class name

Comment: " I think you'll have other methods with IIOManager you should maintain 1st test (update stub), but do nothing on the second one." im sorry i dont understand. Could u elaborate please.

Comment: IIOManager - is interface, so your stub depends from interface. You'll have to update the stub after any changes in IIOManager (for example add another method). Mock (2nd test) doesn't depend from interface implementation. So, the 2nd test easier to maintain then 1st